# Function that don't create SpatialGridDataFrame object

Tags: r, function, spatial, r-raster

I try to create a function that transform digital number of satellite imagery in radiance, but I don't know why my final object is numeric and not a SpatialGridDataFrame object, if I specified in my function class(results) == "SpatialGridDataFrame". 
My code is:

## Packages

```
require(raster)
require(sp)
```

## RasterLayer simulated

```
r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r <- setValues(r, 1:ncell(r))
plot(r)

band2<- as(r, 'SpatialGridDataFrame')  ### convert in SpatialGridDataFrame
```

### Function for DN to radiance

```
radconvL<-function(x, band = 2)
{
     Lmax <- switch(as.character(band), 
                    "2" = 120.64,
                    "3" = 151.31,
                    "4" = 157.57,
                    "5" = 69.03,
                    NA)

     if (is.na(Lmax)) stop("invalid band")

     Lmin = 0
     Qmax = 127
     x <- as.vector(as.matrix(x))
     results <- x

     x <- Lmin + ((Lmax-Lmin)*x)/Qmax
     if (class(results) == "SpatialGridDataFrame")
         results@data[, 1] <- x
     else if (is.data.frame(x))
         results <- data.frame(matrix(x, nrow = nrow(results),
             ncol = ncol(results)))
     else results <- x
     print(paste(band, Lmax))
     print(results)
     results
}
```

--

## Try the function

```
teste2<-radconvL(band2, band = 2)
str(test2)## Numeric!!!! Why???
```

Could someone help me?

Thanks,

Alexandre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll show how you can make this work:

```
radconvL <- function(x, band = 2) {
     Lmax <- switch(band, 
                    "2" = 120.64,
                    "3" = 151.31,
                    "4" = 157.57,
                    "5" = 69.03,
                    NA)

     if (is.na(Lmax)) stop("invalid band")
     Lmin = 0
     Qmax = 127
     Lmin + ((Lmax-Lmin)*x)/Qmax
}

library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
test <- radconvL(b[[2]], band = 2)
```

`test` is a `RasterLayer`, but if you need a `SpatialGridDataFrame` (why?) use:

```
sptest <- as(test, 'SpatialGridDataFrame')
```

This is not a direct answer of your question, but it is very difficult to understand why you are doing some of the things you do in the function. For example, you do:

```
 x <- as.vector(as.matrix(x))
 results <- x
 x <- Lmin + ((Lmax-Lmin)*x)/Qmax
```

so `results` and `x` are a vector, but then you do:

```
if (class(results) == "SpatialGridDataFrame")
#(...)
else if (is.data.frame(x))
#(...)
else results <- x
```

How is that relevant, when we know that `x` is a vector (and not a `SpatialGridDataFrame` or a `data.frame`)? This is always going to make `results` equal to `x`. So it is obvious that the result will always be numeric.

You state that you do: `class(results) == "SpatialGridDataFrame"`, but you do not do that. Either way, that would not work (that is akin to putting a post-it with "car" on your bicycle; that won't magically give it four wheels and an engine all of a sudden).

If you want to speed up things by loading all values into memory, you can do:

```
radconvL <- function(x, band = 2) {
     Lmax <- switch(band, 
                    "2" = 120.64,
                    "3" = 151.31,
                    "4" = 157.57,
                    "5" = 69.03,
                    NA)

     if (is.na(Lmax)) stop("invalid band")
     Lmin = 0
     Qmax = 127
     setValues(x, Lmin + ((Lmax-Lmin)*values(x))/Qmax)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much RobertH for your aswer!!! My problem in use SpatialGridDataFrame is related to processor speed, I have satellite image with 28250001 pixels, you can image the time spend if I use raster format directly?

Comment: That may not matter very much,  I think (and see `rasterOptions` to use more RAM). But I have added another version of the function that computes on a vector.